# Complexity - determining the order of growth

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, division

I understand how to calculate a function's complexity for the most part. The same goes for determining the order of growth for a mathematical function. [I probably don't understand it as much as I think I do, which is why I'm probably asking this.] For instance:

`an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d` could be written as O(n^3) in big-o notation, since for large enough `n`the values of the term `bn^2 + cn + d` are insignificant in comparison to `an^3` (the constant coefficients a, b, c and d are left out as well, as their contribution to the value become insignificant, too).

What I don't understand is, how does this work when the leading term is involved in some sort of division? For instance:

`a/n^3 + bn^2` or `n^3/a + bn^2`

Let n=100, a=1000 and b=10 for the former formula, then we have

`n^3/a = 100^3/1000 = 1000` and `bn^2 = 10*100^2 = 100,000`

or even more dramatic for the latter - in this case the leading term is not only growing slowly as above, but it's also shrinking, isn't it?:

`a/n^3 = 1000/100^3 = 0.001` and `bn^2 = 100,000` as above.

In both cases the second term contributes much more, so isn't it `n^2`that actually determines the order of growth?

It gets even more complicated (for me, at least) when the leading term is followed by a subtraction (`a/n^3 - bn^2`) or when the second term is also a division (`n^3/a + n^2/b)` or when both are divisions but in mixed order (`a/n^3 + n^2/b`), etc.

The list seems endless, so my general question is, how to understand and handle formulas that involve division (and subtraction) in order to determine the order of growth for a given function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A division is just a multiplication by the [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse), so `n^3/a == n^3 * a^-1`, and you can handle it the same way as any other coefficient.

With regards to substraction `a*n^3 - b*n^2 <= a*n^3`, so it is also in `O(n^3)`. Also, `a*n^3 - b*n^2 >= a/2 * n^3` for large enough values of `n`, and it is also in `Omega(n^3)`. A more detailed explanation about substraction can be found in: [Algorithm complexity when faced with substraction in value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29706119/572670)

big O notation is generally used for increasing (don't have to be monotonically) functions, and a decreasing function such as `a/n` is not a good fit for it, though `O(1/n)` seems to be still perfectly defined, AFAIK, and it is a subset of `O(1)` (unless you take into account only discrete functions). However, this has very little value for algorithm's analysis, as a complexity of an algorithm cannot really shrink..

Comment: Taking the inverse is very clever, but would this also work when it's `a/n^3`? Because then we would get `a * (n^3)^-1`

Comment: @Beko No, only to the coefficient. I referred to `a/n` (and obviously for any similar functions) in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, does this mean that functions such as `a/n` aren't really considered in algorithm analysis?

Comment: @AmiTavory Alright, but what if we have `a/n^2 + an`. So `a/n^2 = O(1)` but `an = O(n)`.

Comment: @Beko No, a/n^2 + an is in O(n)

Comment: @Beko amit is right. Please see my answer below which addresses all this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple rule for the type of questions you posted.

Suppose you're trying to find the order of growth of `f(n)`, and you find some simple function `g(n)` such that

```
lim {n -> inf} f(n) / g(n) = k
```

where `k` is a positive finite constant. Then

```
f(n) = Theta(g(n))
```

(It's easy to see this from the calculus definitions.)

Now let's see how this applies to your examples:

```
lim {n -> inf} (a/n^3 + bn^2) / n^2 = b
```

so it's `Theta(n^2)`.

```
lim {n -> inf} (a n^3 - bn^2) / n^3 = a
```

so it's `Theta(n^2)`.

(of course, assuming a and b are positive.)